# Associative Property

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

What I learn as a basic theory of associative is that $$(a \times b) \times c = a \times (b \times c) \text{ and } (a+b)+c = a+(b+c).$$

However when doing my exercises on this topic, I came across questions with only 2 variables. Eg. $a^2+b^2$. Is this associative and why?

The binary operation is given as $a * b = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think the OP is saying if $a*b:=a^2+b^2$, is this an associative operation or not?

Comment: That certainly seems like a likely meaning, but a person wanting help gets better help if he is explicit about what he is asking, rather than oblique. @gt6989b

Comment: I dunno.  If a person legitimately want help because he doesn't understand a concept, then the person *can't* be explicit because he doesn't understand the concept well enough to know how to be explicit.  I think the OP's question *is* explicit.  To say something is associative is to describe three variables but that definition only has two; how is that possible.  It's an explicit question, albeit it a fundamentally confused one.

Answer (score 2):

It's not associative. We have 
$$(a*b)*c=(a^2+b^2)*c=(a^2+b^2)^2+c^2,$$
while
$$a*(b*c)=a*(b^2+c^2)=a^2+(b^2+c^2)^2.$$
If you take for example $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=3$ you get
$$(a*b)*c=34$$
and
$$a*(b*c)=170.$$

Comment: Or even $(a,b,c) = (1,0,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a binary operation only needs two variables to define it.  The operation however needs be performable upon all the elements of a group.  Associativity needs to be shown on three variables but most hold true for all elements.

So although the $a*b := a^2 + b^2$ is *described* with two variables it can be *performed* on all.

So to show * is associative you must show: $a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$ or in other words does $a^2 + (b^2 + c^2)^2$ always equal $(a^2 + b^2)^2 + c^2$.

Comment: Alright. This is another question. a∗b:= (a+b)^2. My solution is
it is not associative as
(a∗b)∗c= (a+b)^2 +c^2
while
a∗(b∗c)= a^2 +(b+c)^2.

Is my working correct?

Comment: \* is not universally defined.  It's a symbol to represent any possible binary operation.  If I understand your question then I believe you had an exercise in which \* was defined to be $a*b = a^2 + b^2$ (and in the next exercise it will be defined as something else).  That *is* a binary operation but is it associative.? No, it isn't and you are right (a∗b)∗c= (a+b)^2 +c^2 and  a∗(b∗c)= a^2 +(b+c)^2.  But you have to show that those two are not always equal.  (Which is really easy to do.)

Comment: I think I understand the concept better now. Thank you,

Comment: To be pendantic, and I think I should be in introductory lessons, when we define a\*b as a^2 + b^2 we should specify what set a and b belong to and whether "+" and ^2 have the meanings we assume they do.  I'm assuming that somewhere in the exercise it was declared that a and b were real numbers (or maybe integers or natural numbers) and that addition and exponentiation were the usual real addition and exponentiation operations?

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS**

If $a*b := a^2 + b^2$, what is $(a*b)*c$ and what is $a*(b*c)$? Can you check if they are the same?

Answer (score 0):

"$+$" and "$\times$" are binary operations; the statement that they are associative of course uses three variables.

The question is: Given a binary operation $*$ defined by $a * b = a^2 + b^2$, is it associative? That is, is it true that
$$
a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c?
$$
Hint: no. Expand the left- and right-hand sides, using the definition of $*$, and find $a,b,c$ for which the two expressions are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

The property of a binary operation $a*b$ be associative allows us that the expression $a*b*c$ (and $a_1*a_2*.....a_n$ for a finite number n, in particular $\Sigma a_i$ and  $\prod a_i$) be well defined. When this is not the case, you have in general $(a*b)*c\ne a*(b*c)$ so $a*b*c$ has no an univocal  sense which happen with your operation $a*b=a^2+b^2$

Answer (score 0):

For $a\ast b$ to be associative it *should* be
$$(a\ast b)\ast c=a\ast (b\ast c),\text{ for all }a,b,c\in \Bbb R,\tag{1}$$
since I assume we are discussing a sum of squares of real numbers. This is, it should be
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+c^2=a^2+(b^2+c^2)^2,\ \forall a,b,c\in \Bbb R.$$
But now it's not difficult to find a counterexample to the above equality:
$$(0^2+1^2)^2+2^2=(0+1)^2+2^2=1^2+2^2=1+4=5$$
while
$$0^2+(1^2+2^2)^2=0+(1+4)^2=0+5^2=0+25=25.$$
Since $(0\ast 1)\ast 2\ne 0\ast (1\ast 2)$, $(1)$ does not hold, this is
$$a\ast b:=a^2+b^2$$
is not associative over the real numbers (and it is not over any subset of reals containing $0$, $1$ and $2$, like $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb N$).